# How to create gray scale QImage(QImage::Format_Indexed) without copying memory

Tags: qt, opencv

I'm trying to create QImage that wrap a existing image buffer that is created by OpenCv
I was considering use following constructor to do this.

```
QImage::QImage ( const uchar * data, int width, int height, 
                 int bytesPerLine, Format format )
```

so, my code is like

```
QImage qimage((const uchar*)iplImage->imageData, 
              iplImage->width, iplImage->height, 
              iplImage->widthStep, 
              QImage::Format_Indexed);     // image buffer not copied!
qimage.setColorTable(grayScaleColorTable); // color table's item count 256 for grayscale.
                                           // now new image buffer is allocated here.
```

Ok, no memory copy actually was done at the time of calling this ctor. 
But, here comes my problem. `QImage::setColorTable()` is non const member function where QImage allocates new image buffer for copying by its internal detach() function.

I found there was Qt3 support for this kind of problem where ctor could accept color table as argument in its ctor, but I've not found any such support in > Qt4.

How can I create gray scale QImage for existing image buffer?

Thanks for in advance

[EDITED]

Thanks to Stephen Chu, I realized that following contstructors create read/write-able QImage object

```
    QImage ( uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format )
    QImage ( uchar * data, int width, int height, int bytesPerLine, Format format )
```

which even if `QImage::setColorTable()` is called later right after instantiation, no new buffer is allocated. On the other hand, following constructors receiving 'const'ed data buffer create read-only QImage objects which new buffer is allocated and deep copied from original buffer when any non-const member function like `QImage::setColorTable()` is called(that I do not want).

```
    QImage ( const uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format )
    QImage ( const uchar * data, int width, int height, int bytesPerLine, Format format )
```

Comment: Why do you think `QImage::setColorTable()` makes a copy of the buffer?

Comment: I didn't think. frankly I didn't even expected it. but It did(I stepped  into `QImage::setColorTable()` and found it allocates new buffer via calling its internal `detach()` function there

Comment: Cast your imageData to non-const in the constructor. Looks like if the ref is 1 and the data is not constant, then it won't duplicate the data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually the result is same. I edited my original code.

Comment: No. Cast it to *non* const. `QImage qImage((uchar*)iplImage->imageData,...`